# How do I set the type of a generic superclass in Java?

Tags: java

Say I have a generic class of type E, and I want a subclass of that generic that always is the type MyObject. So the Generic class can still be used for other objects, but the subclass NonGeneric is always of type MyObject and has MyObject specific functions.

Ex:

```
public class Generic <T extends Comparable <T>>
```

And what I want is some

```
public class NonGeneric<MyObject> extends Generic<T>
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you are trying to create a `class Subclass extends Generic<String> {}`? I could easily be wrong, but I think you can just extend the generic class.

Comment: Can you show some code with the error you experienced?

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

I did not properly flesh out my type that I was trying to use, and had extended the `Comparable` interface instead of `Comparable<MyObject>`

The reason this is the answer to the above question was that the fact that my non-generic type object that I wished to insert didn't correctly implement Comparable prevented me from declaring the non-generic class, throwing an error. I was just too confused to consider the basics.

The correct declaration, once my underlying bug was fixed, is

`public class NonGeneric extends Generic<MyObject>`

Where

`MyObject extends Comparable<MyObject>`

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question you were asking. Please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Edited Answer for clarity.